# Cannot populate spinner from remote database

Tags: android

Another Android beginner here!

Ok, I derped when using Toast to help me check for errors. I'm getting a 403 forbidden error, and I don't know what's causing it. The url is correct, since another function of mine returns data from the database.

```
public class FillKeg extends Activity {

    Spinner spinBeerList;
    ArrayList<String> BeerList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fillkeg);
        spinBeerList = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinBeerList);
        BeerList = new ArrayList<String>();
        new getBeerList().execute("http://*****/kegdroid/getBeerList.php");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, BeerList);    
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinBeerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class getBeerList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            //http post
            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                try{
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            try{
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    BeerList.add(json_data.getString("ContentsName"));
                }    
            }
            catch(JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (ParseException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: NO. NEVER. EVER. DO HTTP STUFF ON UI THREAD. THIS. IS. BAD.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to implement AsyncTask. However, the Spinner is still not populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel really stupid about this, but my error stemmed from an Apache configuration and not the application code. The recent Apache update for my WAMP installation denied access from calls to my network IP.

Big thanks to OcuS and Brian Cooley for helping resolve other areas of my code!

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the `ArrayList` backing your `Adapter` without calling `notifyDataSetChanged`. Try adding a call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to the end of `onPostExecute`.

Alternatively, you can call `adapter.add(json_data.getString("ContentsName"));` in place of the similar call to `BeerList` and the `Spinner` should update automatically.

Comment: That wasn't the solution to this particular problem (figured that out myself, and feel foolish about what caused it), but it did resolve an issue I was going to look up next. So thanks for that!